# Ruby net/http can't connect to a TLS proxy

Tags: ruby

Rubys net/http allows you to specify a proxy to route all requests through like this:

```
Net::HTTP.new("host", "443", "proxyHost", 8080, "proxyUsername", "password")
```

This works fine when used with HTTP proxy however fails when a TLS proxy used instead of HTTP:

```
def tls_proxy(data)

  uri = URI("https://example.com/post")
  client = Net::HTTP.new("host", "443", "proxyHost", 8443, "proxyUsername", "password")

  client.ssl_version = :TLSv1_2
  client.use_ssl = true

  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)

  request['Content-type'] = 'application/json'
  request.body = data

  client.request(request)

end
```

```
Uncaught exception: end of file reached
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:225:in `rbuf_fill'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:191:in `readuntil'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:201:in `readline'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:40:in `read_status_line'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:29:in `read_new'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:969:in `connect'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:930:in `do_start'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:919:in `start'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1470:in `request'
    /Users/laptop/Projects/tls-proxy-ruby/example-https.rb:47:in `tls_proxy'
    /Users/laptop/Projects/tls-proxy-ruby/example-https.rb:60:in `<top (required)>'
```

Is there a way to make it work with TLS proxy or perhaps there is an alternative to this library that supports TLS proxy?

Answer (score -1):

You could try [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) gem instead.

```rb
require 'httparty'

options = {
  http_proxyaddr: '127.0.0.1',
  http_proxyport: '8443',
  http_proxyuser: 'johndoe',
  http_proxypass: '123456'
}

response = HTTParty.get('https://example.com', options)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to support TLS proxy either, I stood up 2 proxies, one that exposes a TLS port(8443) and one just HTTP(8080), if I try submitting a request using the HTTP proxy the request goes through just fine while the TLS port returns the same error as 'net/http' would return "Uncaught exception: end of file reached".